# Unexpected behavior with material ui Select and 'redux-form'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, redux-form

I have a simple 'redux form' with a `Select` component from **newest** material-ui-next.

`import { TextField } from 'material-ui';`

```
<Field
   name="name"
   component={TextField}
   select
>
   <MenuItem value={1}>Lily</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value={2}>Mark</MenuItem>
</Field>
```

Works fine. **Hovewer**, if I change the `value` prop from typeof `number` to `string`, e.g.

```
<Field
   name="name"
   component={TextField}
   select
>
   <MenuItem value="lily">Lily</MenuItem>
   <MenuItem value="mark">Mark</MenuItem>
</Field>
```

the value changes properly, **but** just after one second, the **value** becomes `0` (as it was initially), and the selected value **disappears** (it's empty from now on). It had a correct value just for a moment, but somehow it's being automatically set back to `0`.

Even tried with rendering the field:

```
const renderSelectField = ({ input, label, meta: { touched, error }, children, ...custom }) => (
  <TextField
    {...input}
    select
    onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(event.target.value)}
    children={children}
    {...custom}
  />
)
```

Still, it changes the value, and just after that it returns to `0`. If I `console.log` the form values, it shows up (after manually changing the value):

```
{ name: "Lily" }
{ name: 0 }
{ name: 0 }
```

(it happens in period of one second)

Looking forward for any help. Thank you.

Edit: This is what happens in redux dev tools, when choosing an item with `string` value - in this case `pln`.

[image]

Comment: Could you include the list of actions fired between the two events? You can use https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools for that.

Comment: @squgeim I added an image

Comment: This is the change in state. Could you include the actions (the list on the left).

Comment: @squgeim The only important difference between these two actions (except action type) is payload. Change payload is `pln`. Blur payload is `0`.

Comment: So there are no other actions dispatched in the one second between these two?

Comment: @squgeim Seems like nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [react-select issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1415) and this [redux-form issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1185) it seems like you need to override the default `onBlur` event.

Comment: @Patrickkx how did you solve this issue? What changes did you make to your code in the original question?

Comment: @JamesJ.Just overwrited the `onblur` function which comes in props from redux-form field in my componen. You have to basically overwrite it, like `onBlur={null}`